# Node JS best practices for static string mappers

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am running a Node JS app (Sails JS, but shouldn't matter) and MongoDB (also shouldn't matter).

I have a database model that the WebApp saves many instances of it. For simplicity, let us take a **UserActivityHistory** model example (the example is not my real case, so nevermind the logic).

One of the members of the model is **"ActivityType"**, which can be a **medium-long text** but can be chosen from a static set. For example:

- ActivityType may be one of the following:

  1. "User added a new account".
  2. "User changed account password".

So, assume that I am going to save thousands of instances, I prefer to **save activity type identifier/code** for memory performance. For example:

Instead of saving "User added a new account", the **WebApp should save "UANC"**.

When the user wants to view the "UserActivityHistory", I want to have a static mapper (maybe global variable?) that is some kind of dictionary as follows:

- **["UNAC"] = "User added a new account"**
- **["UCAP"] = "User changed account password"**

Which means, I receive the code of the activity and returns the text from a static dictionary that is saved in the server memory running the application.

**What is the most efficient way and best practices to achieve this mapping?**

The ways I thought of:

1) **Global variables**: saving a global dictionary and add/remove values from it by API calls. I am not sure if this is a wise idea, I still do not see why not, but still deep in my heart something is telling me do not trust global variables.

2) **Saving mappers in another database**: this requires another call to the database for each set of activities. (doesn't seem so heavy to me, if I load many activities at once, but still there could be a better solution).

- Note that I want to add dynamic activities, so having a function with a switch case is not a proper solution.

Comment: How likely is it that these strings would change in the future? Hard-coding them into the app would mean having to re-deploy every time this happens.

Comment: yeah, that's what i am trying to avoid, they are likely to be changed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to redeploy your app everytime a string changes then I would recommend you look at pulling these from some persistant storage (e.g. external file / DB).

Regardless of which you choose, given they are application settings, you would pull them once either as the app starts or on first access. This would give you the flexibility of changing them out-with the app (or perhaps even *from* the app).

---

To answer your comments

> If I pull them as the app starts on first access, where should I save them? global variable?

Well the natural thing to do here would be to have it as it's own module, this would give you a good place to have other methods for manipulating the list & persisting to storage. If you go for the singleton approach then you could load the resource on first access e.g.

**ActivityType.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var cache = null;
function loadCache(callback) {
    if (!cache) {
        fs.readFile('/path-to-strings', function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                // for the purpose of the example, lets assume you are storing the 
                // strings as a JSON object e.g. { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2' }
                cache = JSON.parse(data);
                callback(null, cache);
            } else {
                callback(err, null);
            }
        });
    } else {
        callback(null, cache);
    }
};
module.exports = {
    get: function(key, callback) {
        loadCache(function(err, cache) {
            callback(err, (cache || {})[key]);
        });
    },
    add: function(key, value, callback) {
        loadCache(function(err, cache) {
            if (err) {
                if (callback) callback(err);
            } else {
                cache[key] = value;
            }
        });
    },
    remove: function(key, callback) {
        loadCache(function(err, cache) {
            if (err) {
                if (callback) callback(err);
            } else {
                delete cache[key];
            }
        });
    },
    save: function(callback) {
        loadCache(function(err, cache) {
            if (err) {
                if (callback) callback(err);
            } else {
                var data = JSON.stringify(cache, null, 4); // save formatted for easier editing
                fs.writeFile('/path-to-strings', data, callback);   
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**App.js**

```
var ActivityType = require('./ActivityType');
...
ActivityType.get('UNAC', function(err, text) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(text);
    } else {
        console.log('Unable to load string');
    }
});
ActivityType.add('UCAP', 'User changed account password');
ActivityType.remove('UNAC');
ActivityType.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('Saved successfully!');
    } else {
        console.log('Unable to save strings');
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could have an explicit `load` or `init` method you could call during app startup.

> How expensive is the redeployment of the app?

That's not something I could answer as there is not enough information here, only you know how expensive a redeployment of your app would be. Regardless, surely updating a DB record or changing a resource file is *far* simpler than a redeployment?

Comment: 1. If I pull them as the app starts or on first access, where should I save them? global variable? 2. How expensive is the redeployment of the app?

Comment: Thank you, this is the best approach I can think of. Just to leave no doubt: In case I want to add/remove mappings, I then write new JSON  object to the "/path-to-strings" JSON file (overwrite) which is part of my app, right?

Comment: @user2867106 yeah if you were going for the JSON file approach yeah that's what you would do. I have went to the liberty of updating the example to be more complete going on that basis (with error propagation etc.)